# How to create an evolutive form in angularjs2 using FormBuilder (And the ionic v2 framework)

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-formbuilder

I have the following code working, but I can't display custom error from input nor disable the form if it's not correct. So I would like to convert it to `FormBuilder`. But the problems is that I don't know how manage the adding and removing question in the form.

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

 
@Component({
 templateUrl: 'build/pages/add-question/add-question.html',
 providers: [BddService]
})
export class AddQuestionPage {

 public questions;

 constructor(private nav: NavController, private bddService : BddService) {
  this.questions = [];
  this.addQuestion();
 }

 public addQuestion(){
  var question ={
   category:'',
   material:'',
   chapter:''
  }
  this.questions.push(question);
 }

 public removeQuestion(index: number){
  if(this.questions.length > 1){
   delete this.questions[index];
  }
 }

}
```

```html
<ion-content class="add-question">
  <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveQuestion()">
    <ion-list>
      <div class="question" *ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index ">  
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label stacked>Category</ion-label>
          <ion-input  type="text" [(ngModel)]="questions[i].category" required>
          </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label stacked>Material</ion-label>
          <ion-input  type="text" [(ngModel)]="questions[i].material" required>
          </ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </div>
      <ion-item>
        <button type="button" (click)="addQuestion()" full light>Add Question</button>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <button type="submit" full light>Save Question</button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: It is possible :) What seems impossible about it?

Comment: Because i can do something like this but it's not evolutive 
this.addUserForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   'username' : ['', Validators.required],
   'password' : ['', Validators.required],
   'role' : ['student'],
   'class' : [''],
   'givenCourse' : ['']
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {NavController} from "ionic-angular";
import {FormBuilder, ControlArray, Validators} from "@angular/common";

class Question {
    category: string;
    material: string;
    chapter:  string;
}

@Component({
    templateUrl: "build/pages/evolutive/evolutive.html"
})
export class EvolutivePage {

    questions: Array<Question>;
    evolutiveForm: ControlArray;

    constructor(public nav: NavController, private fb: FormBuilder) {

        this.questions = [];
        this.evolutiveForm = new ControlArray([]);
    }

    saveEvolutive($event, questions) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        console.log(questions);
    }

    addQuestion(): void {
        let q = new Question();
        this.evolutiveForm.push(this.fb.group({
            category: [q.category, Validators.required],
            material: [q.material, Validators.required]
        }));
        this.questions.push(q);
    }

    removeQuestion(i: number): void {
        this.questions.splice(i, 1);
        this.evolutiveForm.removeAt(i);
    }
}
```

And for your template:

```html
<ion-content padding class="evolutive">
    <form [ngFormModel]="evolutiveForm" (submit)="saveEvolutive($event, questions)">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item-group *ngFor="let q of questions; let i = index" ngControlGroup="{{i}}">
                <ion-item-divider light>Question {{+i+1}} <ion-icon name="close" (click)="removeQuestion(i)" item-right></ion-icon></ion-item-divider>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>Category</ion-label>
                    <ion-input ngControl="category" [(ngModel)]="q.category"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
                <ion-item>
                    <ion-label>Material</ion-label>
                    <ion-input ngControl="material" [(ngModel)]="q.material"></ion-input>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-item-group>
        </ion-list>
        <button block type="button" (click)="addQuestion()">Add Question</button>
        <button block type="submit" [disabled]="!evolutiveForm.valid">Save Player</button>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

If you want to add custom validation, you can add them in the `addQuestion()` function where you create the new `ControlGroup` for each question. As it is, it just checks to see that every field has been filled in.

Comment: I updated the code to allow you to remove specific questions.

Comment: Thanks you, it works. Last question for you because u seem really good ahah. If i want an array of options peer the question i can do the same way ?

Comment: Yeah just add more fields along with each question

Comment: I always have a problem so I post a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219449/angular2-controlarray-inside-controlgroup-inside-controlarray